# Slack API get user join to the team date

Tags: slack, slack-api

Is there a way to get user join date to the team via Slack API? The best would be to have all the users and their join dates in the same JSON. Searched through https://api.slack.com/methods , but was not able to find such a method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its in the API method [`team.accessLogs`](https://api.slack.com/methods/team.accessLogs). There you get the property `date_first`, which is the date when that user first logged into Slack.

This method is for payed teams only. But you can track that information yourself with a small app that listens to [`team_join`](https://api.slack.com/events/team_join) event.

Comment: According to the docs, `date_first` is a unix timestamp of the first access log entry for this user, IP address, and user agent combination. That doesn’t sound the same as joining the team.